# YourKit: Could not find agent library in absolute path

Tags: java, agent, yourkit

Using 64-bit Windows 7 Enterprise, according to [YourKit docs](http://yourkit.com/docs/java/help/agent.jsp):

> To check that Java can load the profiler agent, invoke the following command that prints a description of agent parameters:
>
> `java -agentpath:<full agent library path>=help`

Why am I encountering this error, if the library definitely exists?

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not find agent library in absolute path: "full agent library path"

Answer (score 1):

Please pay attention of JVM and profiler agent bitness. It is quite possible that you are using 64-bit agent for 32-bit Java or vice versa.

Comment: You are quite right, I was mistakenly assuming that the JRE installed on my Windows7 machine would be 64 bit. In fact it was 32 bit.